# make bootstrap div responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I want to show 5 images in one row.So one row 5 column
for 5 column I find this css

```
  .col-half-offset {
            margin-left: 4.166666667%
        }
```

this is work for web but for mobile it does no show correctly although I added responsive attribute to my img element,what is problem with this ?

here is my 
css

```
.col-xs-2 {
        /*background:#00f;
    color:#FFF;*/

    }

    .col-half-offset {
        margin-left: 4.166666667%
    }
```

and here is my html

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-responsive">
                        <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                            <p>ISO 1002:2014 Müşteri Memnuniyeti Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 9001-1.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-responsive">
                        <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                            <p>ISO 9001:2015 Kalite Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 14001-1.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Lights">
                        <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                            <p>ISO 14001:2015 Çevre Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 27001-1.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-responsive">
                        <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                            <p>ISO 14001:2013 Bilgi Güvenliği Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/OHSAS 18001-1.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                        <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                            <p>OHSAS 18001:2007 İş Sağlığı Güvenliği Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to the same output in mobile? 5 column in a row?

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist yes ...or maybe 5 row but i think this will be hard ..this work in web good: https://i.hizliresim.com/QPypDV.png  but in mobile it does not look good...here is my website:  http://psldanismanlik.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

In Bootstrap 4, For **Responsive Image** you have to use `img-fluid` not `img-responsive`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       <div class="thumbnail">
           <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-fluid">
               <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                  <p>ISO 1002:2014 Müşteri Memnuniyeti Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
               </div>
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       <div class="thumbnail">
           <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-fluid">
               <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                  <p>ISO 1002:2014 Müşteri Memnuniyeti Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
               </div>
           </a>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="col">
       <div class="thumbnail">
           <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-fluid">
               <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                  <p>ISO 1002:2014 Müşteri Memnuniyeti Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
               </div>
           </a>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="thumbnail">
           <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-fluid">
               <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                  <p>ISO 1002:2014 Müşteri Memnuniyeti Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
               </div>
           </a>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="thumbnail">
           <a href="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="http://psldanismanlik.com/Upload/ISO 1002-1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="img-fluid">
               <div col-xs-12 class="caption">
                  <p>ISO 1002:2014 Müşteri Memnuniyeti Yönetim Sistemi.</p>
               </div>
           </a>
        </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ilazycoder/9xuym2kj/6/

Comment: this not work.In your sample 5 row 5 line...I want only one row or line with five column  http://psldanismanlik.com/  here is demo

Comment: It is one row and five column. Count  carefully.

Comment: What you are wanting it is giving the exact result.

Comment: I want this: https://i.hizliresim.com/zGy0QY.png ..with my code this work very well for web but in mobile it is too ugly...  with your code it generate this for web: https://i.hizliresim.com/9Ybmvk.png  I want 5 image with same row

Comment: Nothing is in your link 403 Forbidden

Comment: I used your div it work very well but your div box are bigger how can I reduce height 10%  ?

Comment: You can give ```max-height: 90%;```